# Raster not loading to PostgreSQL database

Tags: raster, postgis, postgresql, postgis-raster

I am trying to load rasters to my PostgreSQL database with PostGIS enabled.

I am following the tutorial from here for using `raster2pgsql`: https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Raster_Loader

I am able to create the SQL file using the `raster2pgsql` command. However, when I run the sql file using `psql`, it runs and shows the following:
[image]

The raster is also not created in my database. I have ensured that the database and the schema in which I ma trying to import the raster exists. I have also tried the operation with a few different rasters in different projection. The error seems to be the same.

I cannot find the 'ÿ' in the sql file. Even when I search for '_BF', there are no matches. So, it is unlikely to be an encoding issue.

Comment: Maybe somehow the SQL text is generated with different character encoding than what PostgreSQL or psql expects.

Comment: I added to the question that the character is not found in the file. So, I don't think it is an encoding issue.

Comment: If you are on Windows, what does `chcp` show? If it is for example 850 I would do `chcp 65001` and start psql after that again.

Comment: @user30184: Just tried your suggestion. I am still getting the same error. Running your code returns `Active code page: 65001`. Previosly it was `437` as far as I remember

Comment: I fear I don't have more suggestions. Does the same issue happen with all images or just one?

Comment: It happens with all images. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I had a try with commands `raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M orthophoto.tif -F -t 100x100 public.test > orto.sql` and `psql -d test_pg -f orto.sql`. No problem for me. Versions ` PostgreSQL 12.3` and  `PostGIS 3.1)`.

Comment: By changing the code page I managed to get this warning `WARNING: Console code page (65001) differs from Windows code page (1252) 8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference page "Notes for Windows users" for details.`. I still believe that your issue may be due to encodings. I am not sure if your ÿ test is valid or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working for me. I am trying with the population density raster here: https://ftp.maps.canada.ca/pub/nrcan_rncan/Forestry-industry_Industrie-forestiere/CanEcumene/V2-Tiff/ . The spatial reference code is 102009